# Ruby metaprogramming - dynamically defining a new class through a proc?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am trying to set up some Ruby code so that I can dynamically define a new class.  My code right now is as shown below, which I thought would work, but it's not working though, and I'm kind of confused why not.

```
def define_new_class(&block)
  new_class = Class.new(MyClass) do
    yield
  end
end

define_new_class do
  attr_accessor :my_accessor_1

  def initialize
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, but there were a couple of things off. First the argument to `Class.new` defines the superclass of the new class, but `MyClass` was not defined. Secondly you actually want to evaluate the block within the context of the class you are defining instead of just yielding to that block - therefore the `instance_eval`

```
def define_new_class(&block)
  new_class = Class.new do
    self.instance_eval &block
  end
end

a = define_new_class do
  attr_accessor :my_accessor_1

  def initialize
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

My guess is that the reason you had `MyClass` in the first place is that you want the resulting class to be referenceable as `MyClass` If that is the case, you could do something like

```
Object.const_set('MyClass', a)
```

so in one big happy method:

```
def define_new_class(name, &block)
  new_class = Class.new do
    self.instance_eval &block
  end
  Object.const_set(name, new_class)
end

define_new_class('MyClass') do
  attr_accessor :my_accessor_1

  def initialize
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

a = MyClass.new #=> #<MyClass:0x007f8baaaf72c8>
a.my_accessor_1 = 1 #=> 1
a.my_accessor_1 # => 1
```

Comment: I was just using MyClass as a placeholder - it is defined elsewhere.  I set the constant in a different part of the code.  I'll give your `instance_eval` solution a try!

Comment: Alex, I've wondered where `Module#const_set` might be used.  This was helpful in that regard. One small thing: I don't think you need to preface `instance_eval` with `self.`. I've notice `self.` is often added where it's not needed.  Is that to some extent a stylistic preference?

Comment: Yeah definitely a stylistic choice on my part. Just wanted to make it super clear under what context the block was being evaluated. I've heard opinions that you should mostly restrict `self` to attribute setters, but I tend to throw it in more often.

Comment: I think you should use `class_eval` here if you want to define the instance methods. `MyClass.initialize => Hello` in your case, that's to say `initialize` is a class method.